# Transpile an algorithm with user-suppliable callbacks into target language

Tags: haxe

I currently transpile the control flow modeled in an SCXML state-chart onto an [ANSI-C algorithm](https://github.com/tklab-tud/uscxml/blob/master/test/src/test-c-machine.scxml.c) which calls a series of user-supplied callback functions in the correct order, effectively realizing the control flow from the state-chart or ANSI-C. Seeing that more target languages may eventually follow, I was thinking about transpiling onto Haxe as a quasi-canonical form and use their transpilation capabilities to target other languages.

Seeing that Haxe is inherently object-oriented, I guess the best way would be to generate an abstract base class with the transpiled algorithm, which would be extended with implementations of the callbacks.

However, looking at Haxe it seems that this is a rather unorthodox usage and I am at a loss how best to approach it. I cannot find native callbacks in the target language agnostic part of Haxe, so I guess it boils down to target language specific approaches anyway?

**Update:** I want to invoke user-supplied callbacks in the *target language*. The state-chart here merely formalizes a certain control flow. There is no XML parsing involved in Haxe at all, I already parse the XML, process it and generate ANSI-C which accepts user-supplied callbacks. Now I want to take a detour via Haxe to generate any target-language, still, the user-supplied callbacks and all the "scaffolding" is in the target-language.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one listener per callback then just use a function per callback, I prefer to not anticipate what data the listener needs.

Run js example here: https://try.haxe.org/#2a6d2

code below for completeness.

```
class Test {
    static function main() { new Test(); }
    var testing: WithCallback;
    public function new(){
        testing = new WithCallback( output );
        testing.start();
    }
    public function output(){
        trace( 'test ' + testing.val );
    }
}
class WithCallback{
    public var cb: Void->Void;
    public var val: String;
    public function new( cb_: Void -> Void ){
        cb = cb_;
    }
    public function start(){
        for( i in 0...100 ){
            val = 'callback counting ' + Std.string( i );
            if( cb != null ) cb();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want multiple objects to listen then you could look at some Signal type library, I believe Tink ( macro library ) provides one but not tried it.
https://github.com/haxetink/tink_core/blob/master/src/tink/core/Signal.hx

There must be a few signals libraries around.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/hxs/
https://github.com/massiveinteractive/msignal

You may also want to look at how Json can be autoparsed in Haxe with abstracts and typedef using stuff like '@to' and '@from'.
https://haxe.org/manual/std-Json-parsing.html

So for instance a nice way to parse some json with Time field in - is to parse to a typedef with the time field using an abstract around a string and add a method within the abstract so you can get the type from the abstract.
https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html

I think others have worked on a similar approach for xml parsing but if you look into the internals of haxe.Json.parse I am sure you could create a similar approach for xml or binary feeds ( not sure if franco's streams stuff is relevant ).  Also there is an approach to get haxe to generate the typedef code for json parsing based on a sample using really smart macros, but I guess it would be very hard to get haxe macros to construct parser based on data example.

Also you should have a look in the format library it has many example of parsing data.
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/format